# Creating hyperlinks from a list of file names

Tags: notebooks, hyperlink

Suppose I use `FileNames` to get a list of file names.

I know that it's possible to make a hyperlink using this kind of pattern....

```
Cell[TextData[ButtonBox["Link Label", BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",
               ButtonData->{FrontEnd`FileName[{"Folder names"}, "FileName.nb",  
                            CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], None}]],
    "Text"]
```

I would appreciate help with taking a list of file names and writing them as working hyperlinks in a specified notebook.

To be clear,  I'd like the hyperlink to open the file referred to by the hyperlink.

I tried taking a file path,  splitting it to get the parts,  using that for the folder structure and the file name,  but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You want the link to open the file it is referring to? Like: `Button[#, NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], #}]]] & /@ 
 FileNames["*.nb"]`

Comment: Thank you, wow,  that already looks promising.  I tried that,  how would I modify so it looks into "sub-folders".  The above command is fantastic,  but only finds files in the current directory.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please take a look at [`FileNames`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNames.html?q=FileNames&lang=en) documentation. All is there. Have to go now, good luck.

Comment: Thank you... this worked for me...                           Button[#, NotebookOpen[#]] & /@ 
 FileNames[{"*.nb"}, {Directory[]}, Infinity]

Comment: Right,  that was "theoretical",  I wouldn't have folders more than 2 or 3 levels deep... I was just testing to see if it worked.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hyperlink` will work too, so for the record:

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Composition[
  Column,
  Hyperlink[#, FileNameJoin[{Directory[], #}]] & /@ # &
  ]@FileNames["*.nb"]
```

> [image]

Of course you can play with `FileNames` and/or `SetDirectory` to adjust search to your needs.

Comment: Thanks!  and thanks for adding that so I could give you credit for an answer!

Comment: @TomDeVries I'm glad I could help :)